# Why does an Abelian group give the following property?

Tags: group-theory

Let $(R,+)$ be an Abelian group.

In a book I am studying it says that because $(R,+)$ is an Abelian group then it gives the property $(a-b)\in R$, for all $a,b\in R$. What does being Abelian have to do with this property because from what I understand a group is Abelian if $a+b=b+a$ for all $a,b\in R$.

Comment: What book is that? Please quote it in full.

Comment: The property doesn't depend on $(R,+)$ being Abelian. Let $(S,\cdot)$ be a non-Abelian group. Then $\forall a,b \in S : (a \cdot b^{-1}) \in S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right - the property you mention is true  for any group, regardless of its being Abelian:
$$\forall a,b\in R, a-b\in R$$
In all likelihood the author used the word Abelian just to stress that the object in question is Abelian, even though this wasn't strictly necessary for the conclusion.

Comment: Presumably to justify the use of additive notation, in particular the minus sign in front of the inverse.

Comment: oh, I get it  now.

Comment: This is just a repetition of my comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you use additive notation, a group must be closed with $+$. Since $(a-b) = a+(-b)$, where $-b$ is the inverse of $b$ (that must exist in a group), $(a-b) \in R$ is obligatory for a group too, this is not a special attitude of an Abelian group, but it must be true for it too.